# symmetric plotting in splot along x-axis

Tags: plot, gnuplot, heatmap

I am using splot for producing a heat map from the scattered points. What I have is x-axis positive, y in both negative and positive, z accordingly. I would like to plot this symmetrically in the negative x-axis. I used

```
set xrange[0:5]
set yrange[-3:3]
set xrange[0:5] reverse
set cbrange[-2:2]
 splot "all.dat" using 1:2:3 notitle with labels
```

and

I also used changing 1:2:3 to (-$1):2:3
but I could not achieve the desired result.

few data points

```
0.95  -3  0.332246
0.95  -2.95  0.342453
0.95  -2.9  0.352814
0.95  -2.85  0.363333
0.95  -2.8  0.374018
0.95  -2.75  0.384877
0.95  -2.7  0.395919
0.95  -2.65  0.407154
0.95  -2.6  0.418594
0.95  -2.55  0.430251
0.95  -2.5  0.442139
0.95  -2.45  0.454277
0.95  -2.4  0.466682
0.95  -2.35  0.479375
0.95  -2.3  0.492383
0.95  -2.25  0.50573
0.95  -2.2  0.519449
0.95  -2.15  0.533574
0.95  -2.1  0.548143
0.95  -2.05  0.563198
0.95  -2  0.578788
0.95  -1.95  0.594962
0.95  -1.9  0.611778
0.95  -1.85  0.629295
0.95  -1.8  0.647577
0.95  -1.75  0.666692
0.95  -1.7  0.686713
0.95  -1.65  0.707711
0.95  -1.6  0.729761
0.95  -1.55  0.752938
0.95  -1.5  0.777315
0.95  -1.45  0.802964
0.95  -1.4  0.829949
0.95  -1.35  0.858332
0.95  -1.3  0.888166
0.95  -1.25  0.919495
0.95  -1.2  0.952354
0.95  -1.15  0.986765
0.95  -1.1  1.02274
0.95  -1.05  1.06028
0.95  -1  1.09937
0.95  -0.95  1.14
0.95  -0.9  1.18211
0.95  -0.85  1.22568
0.95  -0.8  1.27063
0.95  -0.75  1.3169
0.95  -0.7  1.36441
0.95  -0.65  1.41306
0.95  -0.6  1.46273
0.95  -0.55  1.51331
0.95  -0.5  1.56461
0.95  -0.45  1.61646
0.95  -0.4  1.66864
0.95  -0.35  1.72087
0.95  -0.3  1.77286
0.95  -0.25  1.82431
0.95  -0.2  1.87492
0.95  -0.15  1.92446
0.95  -0.1  1.97287
0.95  -0.05  2.02026
0.95  -9.39526e-15  2.06704
0.95  0.05  2.02026
0.95  0.1  1.97287
0.95  0.15  1.92446
0.95  0.2  1.87492
0.95  0.25  1.82431
0.95  0.3  1.77286
0.95  0.35  1.72087
0.95  0.4  1.66864
0.95  0.45  1.61646
0.95  0.5  1.56461
0.95  0.55  1.51331
0.95  0.6  1.46273
0.95  0.65  1.41306
0.95  0.7  1.36441
0.95  0.75  1.3169
0.95  0.8  1.27063
0.95  0.85  1.22568
0.95  0.9  1.18211
0.95  0.95  1.14
0.95  1  1.09937
0.95  1.05  1.06028
0.95  1.1  1.02274
0.95  1.15  0.986765
0.95  1.2  0.952354
0.95  1.25  0.919495
0.95  1.3  0.888166
0.95  1.35  0.858332
0.95  1.4  0.829949
0.95  1.45  0.802964
0.95  1.5  0.777315
0.95  1.55  0.752938
0.95  1.6  0.729761
0.95  1.65  0.707711
0.95  1.7  0.686713
0.95  1.75  0.666692
0.95  1.8  0.647577
0.95  1.85  0.629295
0.95  1.9  0.611778
0.95  1.95  0.594962
0.95  2  0.578788
0.95  2.05  0.563198
0.95  2.1  0.548143
0.95  2.15  0.533574
0.95  2.2  0.519449
0.95  2.25  0.50573
0.95  2.3  0.492383
0.95  2.35  0.479375
0.95  2.4  0.466682
0.95  2.45  0.454277
0.95  2.5  0.442139
0.95  2.55  0.430251
0.95  2.6  0.418594
0.95  2.65  0.407154
0.95  2.7  0.395919
0.95  2.75  0.384877
0.95  2.8  0.374018
0.95  2.85  0.363333
0.95  2.9  0.352814
0.95  2.95  0.342453
0.95  3  0.332246

0.85  -3  0.335929
0.85  -2.95  0.346217
0.85  -2.9  0.35666
0.85  -2.85  0.367266
0.85  -2.8  0.378042
0.85  -2.75  0.388996
0.85  -2.7  0.400136
0.85  -2.65  0.411474
0.85  -2.6  0.423022
0.85  -2.55  0.434791
0.85  -2.5  0.446798
0.85  -2.45  0.459059
0.85  -2.4  0.471595
0.85  -2.35  0.484425
0.85  -2.3  0.497576
0.85  -2.25  0.511075
0.85  -2.2  0.524954
0.85  -2.15  0.539247
0.85  -2.1  0.553994
0.85  -2.05  0.569237
0.85  -2  0.585024
0.85  -1.95  0.601407
0.85  -1.9  0.618444
0.85  -1.85  0.636193
0.85  -1.8  0.654721
0.85  -1.75  0.674096
0.85  -1.7  0.694389
0.85  -1.65  0.715673
0.85  -1.6  0.738025
0.85  -1.55  0.761517
0.85  -1.5  0.786224
0.85  -1.45  0.812216
0.85  -1.4  0.839559
0.85  -1.35  0.868314
0.85  -1.3  0.898534
0.85  -1.25  0.930263
0.85  -1.2  0.963537
0.85  -1.15  0.998378
0.85  -1.1  1.0348
0.85  -1.05  1.07281
0.85  -1  1.11239
0.85  -0.95  1.15353
0.85  -0.9  1.19619
0.85  -0.85  1.24034
0.85  -0.8  1.28593
0.85  -0.75  1.33289
0.85  -0.7  1.38116
0.85  -0.65  1.43064
0.85  -0.6  1.48125
0.85  -0.55  1.53285
0.85  -0.5  1.58528
0.85  -0.45  1.63836
0.85  -0.4  1.69183
0.85  -0.35  1.74538
0.85  -0.3  1.79861
0.85  -0.25  1.85106
0.85  -0.2  1.90222
0.85  -0.15  1.95164
0.85  -0.1  1.99896
0.85  -0.05  2.04417
0.85  -9.39526e-15  2.08764
0.85  0.05  2.04417
0.85  0.1  1.99896
0.85  0.15  1.95164
0.85  0.2  1.90222
0.85  0.25  1.85106
0.85  0.3  1.79861
0.85  0.35  1.74538
0.85  0.4  1.69183
0.85  0.45  1.63836
0.85  0.5  1.58528
0.85  0.55  1.53285
0.85  0.6  1.48125
0.85  0.65  1.43064
0.85  0.7  1.38116
0.85  0.75  1.33289
0.85  0.8  1.28593
0.85  0.85  1.24034
0.85  0.9  1.19619
0.85  0.95  1.15353
0.85  1  1.11239
0.85  1.05  1.07281
0.85  1.1  1.0348
0.85  1.15  0.998378
0.85  1.2  0.963537
0.85  1.25  0.930263
0.85  1.3  0.898534
0.85  1.35  0.868314
0.85  1.4  0.839559
0.85  1.45  0.812216
0.85  1.5  0.786224
0.85  1.55  0.761517
0.85  1.6  0.738025
0.85  1.65  0.715673
0.85  1.7  0.694389
0.85  1.75  0.674096
0.85  1.8  0.654721
0.85  1.85  0.636193
0.85  1.9  0.618444
0.85  1.95  0.601407
0.85  2  0.585024
0.85  2.05  0.569237
0.85  2.1  0.553994
0.85  2.15  0.539247
0.85  2.2  0.524954
0.85  2.25  0.511075
0.85  2.3  0.497576
0.85  2.35  0.484425
0.85  2.4  0.471595
0.85  2.45  0.459059
0.85  2.5  0.446798
0.85  2.55  0.434791
0.85  2.6  0.423022
0.85  2.65  0.411474
0.85  2.7  0.400136
0.85  2.75  0.388996
0.85  2.8  0.378042
0.85  2.85  0.367266
0.85  2.9  0.35666
0.85  2.95  0.346217
0.85  3  0.335929
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set xrange [0:5] reverse`  does not do what you want.  If you want the x range to be symmetric across zero then it should be `set xrange [-5:5]`, and the plot command something like

```
 unset key
 splot "all.dat" using 1:2:3:3 with labels, "all.dat" using (-$1):2:3:3 with labels
```

This will only place numeric labels, however, not a colored heatmap. Perhaps you want

```
 splot "all.dat" using 1:2:3 with points pt 5 lc palette, \
       "all.dat" using (-$1):2:3 with points pt 5 lc palette
```